# Is there any Visual Studio Extension for display Function Dependency in code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

is there a extension for Visual Studio that can show the **dependence of functions**?  There is a feature in Visual Studio [**Find All References**] the code that calls a function on the project throughout the show.
I am looking for a tool that would show all dependency of functions in the code.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "depndence of functions" and "attachment functions". Can you please be a little bit more descriptive?

Comment: You can generate dependency graph in Vs2010 and 2012 .see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/11/visual-studio-2010-how-to-understand-your-code-using-dependency-graphs-sequence-diagrams-and-the-architecture-explorer.aspx

Comment: Excuse me. it's my mistake and corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate dependancy graph using NDepend which is third party tool. New VS2010 and VS 2012 have these features. Here are some links to get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx

[How do I get a diagram of the dependencies between my C# projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564462/how-do-i-get-a-diagram-of-the-dependencies-between-my-c-sharp-projects)